# Wait for the ie page to load with

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer

Help me please.
Can I somehow help angular.element wait until the IE web page is fully loaded DOM?
In my VBA macro, for example, I click the buttons on the site with this code:

```
oie.document.parentWindow.execScript "angular.element('[data-ng-click=""showText()""]').triggerHandler('click');"
```

Is it possible to use the same code after pressing the button to wait for the full load DOM in IE page?

UPD: on the site after clicking the buttons, a dynamic DOM change occurs and I need to wait for the end of the dynamic change DOM and the page load.

Answer (score 0):

you can use angular.element to target document ready.  the callback function will then execute once the DOM is loaded.

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    angular.element('[data-ng-click="showText()"]').triggerHandler('click');
});
```